# jQuery Conditional Base on URL

Tags: jquery, url, conditional-statements

I have this code below working, except that it only works when the URL is "domain/dev" not "domain/dev/" with the trailing slash. I'm not very familiar with JS syntax so not sure how to correct. I've tried different variations, adding a conditional statement, but the slash seems to be breaking the code.

```
$(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
  if(/dev/.test(loc)) {
    var visited = 'visited';
    if($.cookies.get(visited) === null){
        $('#career-home').addClass('visited')
        $.cookies.set('visited', 'visited')
        console.log("addClass")
    }else{
        $('#career-home').removeClass('visited')
        console.log("removeClass")
    }
  }
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: "seems to be breaking the code" --- define "breaking". But please don't just explain it in a way like "it doesn't work"

Comment: have you tried with : `if("domain/dev/"+loc == 'something') {`

Comment: By "breaking" I mean when I test using example.com/dev/ the conditional returns true. But when I test example.com/dev the conditional returns false. Not exactly sure if "return" is the correct word to use here, but hopefully that helps clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a hack but it should work

```
var loc = window.location.href;
    if(loc.substring(loc.length-1,loc.length) == '/'){
       loc = loc.substring(0,loc.length-1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed (check if cookie is present, if yes add a couple of classes, if not, add one class) using this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var cookieName = pathArray[2];
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    if($.cookies.get(cookieName) === null) {
        $.cookies.set(cookieName, 'visited');
        $('#' + cookieName).addClass('current');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#' + cookieName).addClass('visited')
            console.log("addClass 'visited' to #" + cookieName)
        },5000);
        console.log("Set cookie = " + cookieName)
        console.log("addClass 'current' to #" + cookieName)
    } else {
        console.log(cookieName + " cookie value = " + $.cookies.get(cookieName))        
    }
    if(/dev/.test(loc)) {
        $('#' + cookieName).addClass('current');
    }       
});
```